# C++：Why the program can execute normally without any errors?

Tags: c++

[image]

As you can see, the `main()` function does not contain the statement `return 0;`.
But the program can still execute normally, even though the `main()` function has been specified to return a value of `int`. I just don't understand why. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste text *as text* into your question.

Comment: _As you can see, the `main()` function does not contain the statement `return 0;`..._ No, I can see a `return 0` at line 32 (inside `main()`. :|

Comment: @brc-dd Seems you're the only who looked at the image.

Answer (score 3):

[The `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) is treated differently by the compiler. If there's no `return 0;` at the end then the compiler will implicitly add such a statement.

Note that this is only for the `main` function, you can't omit return statements in any other function.

Answer (score 0):

In your attached image the main function does have a return statement.

Anyways if you don't include a return statement for main, the compiler will do that for you implicitly during compilation process. Although it is a good practice that we include one!

Similarly, even if you don't have a default non-parameterized constructor, a compiler will also include one, with empty body.

Answer (score 0):

> In C++ :

If control reaches the end of the main function, return 0; is executed.

which is  equivalent to first leaving the function normally (which destroys the objects with automatic storage duration) and then calling std::exit with the same argument as the argument of the return.
(std::exit then destroys static objects and terminates the program)

> in C:

If the return statement is used, the return value is used as the argument to the implicit call to exit() (see below for details). The values zero and EXIT_SUCCESS indicate successful termination, the value EXIT_FAILURE indicates unsuccessful termination

[From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)